# Load an EXS24 instrument with a CoreAudio AUSampler in iOS6

Tags: ipad, ios6, core-audio, coremidi

From looking at the AUSampler API it seems like it should support Garage Band EXS24 instruments. The AudioUnitProperties.h file says the following:

```
typedef struct AUSamplerInstrumentData {
    CFURLRef                fileURL;
    UInt8                   instrumentType;
    UInt8                   bankMSB;
    UInt8                   bankLSB;
    UInt8                   presetID;
} AUSamplerInstrumentData;
```

Where the instrument type can have the following types:

```
enum
{
    kInstrumentType_DLSPreset   = 1,
    kInstrumentType_SF2Preset   = kInstrumentType_DLSPreset,
    kInstrumentType_AUPreset    = 2,
    kInstrumentType_Audiofile   = 3,
    kInstrumentType_EXS24       = 4
};
```

I've tried to load the instrument using the following function:

```
-(OSStatus) loadFromEXS: (NSString *) path withSampler: (AudioUnit) sampler {
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    NSURL *presetURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"exs"]];

    AUSamplerInstrumentData bpdata = {0};

    bpdata.fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)(presetURL);
    bpdata.instrumentType = kInstrumentType_EXS24;

    result = AudioUnitSetProperty(sampler,
                              kAUSamplerProperty_LoadInstrument,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              &bpdata,
                              sizeof(bpdata));
    return result;
}
```

In my resources I have a group which contains the .exs file and a number of .wav samples. This function produces the following error:

```
GlobalState::LoadEXS24Instrument: Load failed
```

So does this mean that the EXS file isn't correct? Does it mean that I've not loaded it correctly? Or maybe, this isn't supported in iOS6?

Comment: Suggest you ask on the Apple iOS dev Core Audio forum. iOS6 is still new and not much info about these sorts of changes to the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems like it supports the EXS file format. There's one problem however: EXS uses absolute file paths. It does not support relative paths. That means you can't move the .wav samples around, or it will break the EXS instrument. That's my guess why it isn't working.

See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.html

Comment: This technical note was a reply to an information request I made to Apple. I can confirm that it does work.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Did you fix it?  Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468108/ios-ausampler-audiounit-file-path-issue-with-exs-files